# Using Tesseract-OCR for Live Text Output

Tags: c++, linux, tesseract, c++17

I'd like to state something from the beginning to make things easier for those who answer; I'm a Novice/Beginner Programmer. I understand ***100%*** that I've taken on a project that is years beyond my level. However, this application would help dozens of people I work with, throughout the world, do their jobs better. With that said, let me explain what I'm after, and my questions.

I work in Data Centers as a Tech. Some companies don't give us remote access to servers, we have to physically stand there with a laptop and connect via a USB KVM Console cable. The kicker is, we can't copy text from the screen. We have to **manually** type it, or take a screenshot, and then post it on our ticketing system. The problem with the current options, is that the screen is tiny. Around 800x600. As you can imagine, that takes quite a few screenshots to get the full picture.

I've done a fair amount of Googling, and I haven't found an exact answer to my questions.

1. Can Tesseract extract text on the fly, and not from an image? i.e. During Ubuntu POST, it runs through a bunch of information regarding the system.
2. Can you force Tesseract to only extract text from a certain area?
   I answered 2 without even realizing it, serves me right for having too many tabs open and small font.
3. If the answer to Questions 1 and 2 are yes, can you do this with v3.x.x and v4?
   I read that v3 is better suited for Dual Core Processors, while v4 is better suited for quad core and up.

Final Question, any suggestions or things I should be aware about while working with Tesseract? Everything will be OpenSource, once I've got a working copy, I'll post it to GitHub. I've gotta write a copy for Linux and Windows. Not sure if Mac will be needed but the other two for sure.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you copy text from the screen.

Comment: Hey Dmitrii, Everything I've read has firmly stated from an image. My work around for that, would just take an image in the background, store it locally, and then scan that for the output. I've never worked with GUI's before, most of the C++ i've been exposed too, is from the 90s and it was game oriented. I guess I'll do some more Googling and see what I can dig up. *sigh*